# `detect` and `find` return `nil` whereas `find_all` and `select` return a result

Tags: ruby

With the code below, the byebug trips:

```
cspg_instance = @game_instances.find do |instance|
  instance_end_time = TimeOperation.new(:+, instance.start_time, instance.duration).result
  if (event.end_time > instance.start_time && event.end_time <= instance_end_time && instance.events.first.period == event.period)
    byebug
  end
end
```

This returns the correct result: (edit: this WAS returning the correct result and now returns nil)

```
cspg_instance = @game_instances.find do |instance|
  instance_end_time = TimeOperation.new(:+, instance.start_time, instance.duration).result
  if (event.end_time > instance.start_time && event.end_time <= instance_end_time && instance.events.first.period == event.period)
    ok = true
  end
  ok
end
```

Yet, it returns `nil`, with only the 'if' condition (without the `if` statement); whereas `find_all` and `select` both return a value.

```
cspg_instance = @game_instances.find do |instance|
  instance_end_time = TimeOperation.new(:+, instance.start_time, instance.duration).result

  (event.end_time > instance.start_time && event.end_time <= instance_end_time && instance.events.first.period == event.period)
end
```

I wonder if anyone has any idea what to make of this; perhaps a ruby or installation failure?

Comment: What are the instances in @game_instances? Would you have an example?

Comment: Also, are #find_all and #select returning an empty Array or are there elements in there?

Comment: @game_instances holds Instance model instances; and yes #find_all and #select both return two of these.

Comment: Is `@game_instances` an ordinary `Array`? Or some other object – like an `AR::Relation` for example? What does `@game_instances .class` return?

Comment: "@game_instances.class" returns-- "Instance::ActiveRecord_Relation". OK wow. it works now using the last code block above, after adding ".to_a" to "@game_instances". I had put the last code block into byebug and it returned a value... guess byebug works differently in cases from app environment

Comment: @spickermann, it still seems to me an obscure mystery why the first code block trips the byebug, however... because, clearly the statement evaluates as "true". Perhaps SO has answered this question elsewhere... an issue having to do with 'bundler'(?) as you mentioned

Comment: The important hints was that `@game_instances` is an instance or `AR::Relation` and not an `Array`, because `AR::Relation#find` works totally different than `Array#find`. I updated my answer to address this issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different issues:

1) Why the version with `byebug` doesn't work

This is the important piece from the docs of `find`: *Returns the first for which block is not false.*

Now let's have a look at your cases:

```
# just writing "true" here, with no if statement will deliver a result
```

If you just write `true` at the end of the block then that `true` is returned and therefore `find` finds this entry.

```
if (event.end_time > instance.start_time && event.end_time <= instance_end_time && instance.events.first.period == event.period)
  ok = true
end
ok
```

This case is similar: If the `if` condition is `true` you assign `true` to the `ok` variable. Because you call `ok` again in the last line of the block the block returns `true` and `find` finds this element.

```
if (event.end_time > instance.start_time && event.end_time <= instance_end_time && instance.events.first.period == event.period)
  byebug
end
```

But this example in your code is different. Here you open `bundle` if the `if` condition is `true`. This makes the `bundler` call the last method call in the `find` block. Calling `bundler` doesn't return `true` therefore the whole block doesn't return `true` and `find` doesn't pick these entry.

The solution is to return `true` in the last line of the `find` block. Because you have already the condition in your code, you could use that directly without assigning `true` to a variable first.
 – for example like this:

```
cspg_instance = @game_instances.find do |instance|
  instance_end_time = TimeOperation.new(:+, instance.start_time, instance.duration).result

  event.end_time > instance.start_time && event.end_time <= instance_end_time && instance.events.first.period == event.period
end
```

2) Why does `find_all` and `select` work, but `find` does not?

In the comments, you clarified that `@game_instances` is actually not an Array, but an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. [`ActiveRecord::Relation#find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) works totally different than the method on an `Array`. Simplified `find` on such a relation expects an `id` of a record and returns that record within the scope given by the relation. Calling `to_a` on the relation loads all records into memory an allows you to use `Array#find`.

From a performance point of view it would make sense to translate the condition into a SQL condition and only load the one record that matches from the database instead of loading all records and find the correct one in your application.

Comment: yes, thank you. This last code (the "solution"), however, fails to return an instance, whereas #find_all and #select DO [return 2 instances, both].